# Glitchy mp4 concatenation with ffmpeg concat

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm using the following command to conatenate a set of mp4 files:

```
ffmpeg -auto_convert 1 -f concat -safe 0 -i files.txt -c copy output/all.mp4
```

`files.txt` looks like this:

```
file './SAM_1050.MP4'
file './SAM_1051.MP4'
file './SAM_1052.MP4'
...
```

The output is clean until the end of the first clip. After that, the last frame of the last clip is visible, but gets more and more distorted. Halfway through this is what the video looks like:

[image: The entire frame is just plain grey, with some glitches here and there.]

Here's my `ffmpeg -version` output:

```
$ ffmpeg -version
ffmpeg version 3.3.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 7.1.1 (GCC) 20170516
configuration: --prefix=/usr --disable-debug --disable-static --disable-stripping --enable-avisynth --enable-avresample --enable-fontconfig --enable-gmp --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgsm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxcb --enable-libxvid --enable-shared --enable-version3
libavutil      55. 58.100 / 55. 58.100
libavcodec     57. 89.100 / 57. 89.100
libavformat    57. 71.100 / 57. 71.100
libavdevice    57.  6.100 / 57.  6.100
libavfilter     6. 82.100 /  6. 82.100
libavresample   3.  5.  0 /  3.  5.  0
libswscale      4.  6.100 /  4.  6.100
libswresample   2.  7.100 /  2.  7.100
libpostproc    54.  5.100 / 54.  5.100
```

Comment: Are all clips from the same source?

Comment: All of them are from the same source, expect for some files at the end, but the video gets glithchy waaay before it gets to the different files and afaik the `-auto_convert 1` option should have taken care of it, right?